# RSA: Given (N,e,d+p,c) how to solve

Tags: rsa

Given (N, e , d+p, c). Is it possible to get m?

details:

````
p = getPrime(1024)
q = getPrime(1024)
N = p * q
phin = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
e = 0x10001
d = gmpy2.invert(e, phin)
print d + p
print pow(m, e, N)
print N
#13403884609962575350524257610529569285008943080523307346134953685337776739724306327734876588061124163062645337251208573050864078580999534356263020577433498907868832686750288242823106322040606201997520837506578651200475396523064635936558565669416041659080995474356518476460687888326953711548467220357062387279692173557387184745992925795541433834898123338868236541135278591957560768663069567268618867488292276958973452640241529092739812960635520440424623412100545432883869330202397285519526444919584001022021472395486908635803682403355268769294016539716645996013483882230729388248530192456028452289702543599389061731472
#9619987712873997671799719134332449218583378188423578213883308994242824937581078306137129027677437203407077421311011489691812684920634184349596234589070530353243790224895814888182502619139894797318263799363684273522003335223755338220748798609619433894886691387621814659650001678209909470629517965817807385821855863584099435798430036397993399217581477794798657079305640063983386713395628277233917743748062602706321679350252372644951327469958702789809945114712766533006121698220252916442318865565943803551265988422945586564570997905855895296624286317547902525631115922107705749694534219384000188184663079678075005189164
#27173891350360915047709600984355999079148424000626596762571425114485781983831220459701197356753237054927354455020028343243557370555973844869811908917723859867138914461334291476780954589896223239407044363153668607161987071547996629609126696516117150438060791301478737630828845922519366640695143261686540590687303866020385473538109498328812234072223747986251443267186573429266208264894342843906207249360008336539689056823275973389967653259975393078506318436800597609530823699947079204933156123646207435254861210944566870137893969899215292959207954116720220023515316789130713039645473525977068416524457951698818282336541

```
````

Comment: Looks like a challenge from a competition. Has it finished?